# How to force attr html5 to false in Symfony FormType

Tags: twig, datetimepicker, symfony5

I am trying to deal between Symfony 5 & Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4 Datetimepicker. My Datetime input form only work with an update function, when an event exist. I want to pass an attribute to my form but it seems to doesn't work.

I have this builder :

```
    $builder->add('date', DateTimeType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => [
                'html5' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Date',
                'class' => 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
                'data-target' => '#datetimepicker1'
            ],
        ]);
```

My template :

```
            <div class="row row-datetime">
                <div class="input-group date col" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                    {{ form_widget(form.date, {'html5':false } ) }}
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text datetimepicker-button">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

{% block javascripts %}
    {{parent()}}
    <script>
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
            format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

But the result is unexpected, Chrome returns my input type as "datetime-local".

In another template for editing an existing event, I have this code, Without form_widget :

```
            <div class="row row-datetime">
                <div class="input-group date col" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text datetimepicker-button">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And it works like a charm I don't understand... If I try this code in my first template, Twig create two datetime inputs. One with the datetimepicker and another classic datetime.

I really don't understand.

Can somebody help me with this please ?

Thanks.

Best,

Py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your builder to this:

```
$builder->add('date', DateTimeType::class, [
        'required' => true,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Date',
            'class' => 'datetimepicker-input',
            'data-target' => '#datetimepicker1'
        ],
        'html5' => false,
    ]);
```

Note that the `html5` specification does not go in the `attr` array. Also note that you don't have to add the `form-control` class since symfony will do this on its own where needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Since my question I chose a easiest way, but will try your solution later ! 

Best regards ! 

Py